# Copy Item's Metadata for batching

Tags: msbuild

This is an extension to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5165476/copy-items-metadata-in-msbuild).
Suppose I'm creating items from other item's metadata:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <A>
        <files>f1;f2;f3;...</files>
        <x>...</x>
        <y>...</y>
        <z>...</z>
        ...
    </A>
    <B Include="%(A.files)">
        <x>%(A.x)</x>
        <y>%(A.y)</y>
        <z>%(A.z)</z>
        ...
    </B>
</ItemGroup>
```

`%(A.files)` is a list of files separated by `;`, such that for each A item I'm creating many B items (one for each file).
But frequently when I process `B` item I need the original's `A` item metadata. In this example I copied each metadata manually from `A` to `B`.

Is there a way to copy all of A's metadata to B without explicitly specifying each one of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, MSBuild only copies metadata when there is a one-to-one mapping between the input and output item lists.  In your case, you're starting with one item and expanding to many items.  To get around this, I suggest using item batching:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<Project
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"
    ToolsVersion="4.0"
    DefaultTargets="Print">

    <ItemGroup>
        <A Include="A1">
            <files>test.htm;test_sol1.htm</files>
            <x>a1</x>
            <y>b1</y>
            <z>c1</z>
        </A>
        <A Include="A2">
            <files>test.proj</files>
            <x>a2</x>
            <y>b2</y>
            <z>c2</z>
        </A>
    </ItemGroup>

    <Target Name="ExpandA">
        <ItemGroup>
            <ExpandedA Include="%(A.files)">
                <Original>%(Identity)</Original>
            </ExpandedA>
        </ItemGroup>
    </Target>

    <Target
        Name="CopyMetadata"
        Outputs="%(ExpandedA.Identity)"
        DependsOnTargets="ExpandA">

        <PropertyGroup>
            <ExpandedAIdentity>%(ExpandedA.Identity)</ExpandedAIdentity>
            <ExpandedAOriginal>%(ExpandedA.Original)</ExpandedAOriginal>
        </PropertyGroup>
        <ItemGroup>
            <ExpandedAMetadata Include="@(A)" Condition=" '%(Identity)' == '$(ExpandedAOriginal)' ">
                <Expanded>$(ExpandedAIdentity)</Expanded>
            </ExpandedAMetadata>
        </ItemGroup>
    </Target>

    <Target Name="Print" DependsOnTargets="CopyMetadata">
        <ItemGroup>
            <B Include="@(ExpandedAMetadata->'%(Expanded)')" />
        </ItemGroup>

        <!--Use commas to illustrate that "files" has been expanded-->
        <Message Text="A: %(A.files)" />
        <Message Text="ExpandedA: @(ExpandedA, ',')" />
        <Message Text="ExpandedAMetadata: @(ExpandedAMetadata, ',')" />
        <Message Text="B: @(B->'%(Identity) x:%(x) y:%(y) z:%(z)', ',')" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

and the output of the "Print" target:

```
Print:
  A: test.htm;test_sol1.htm
  A: test.proj
  ExpandedA: test.htm,test_sol1.htm,test.proj
  ExpandedAMetadata: A1,A1,A2
  B: test.htm x:a1 y:b1 z:c1,test_sol1.htm x:a1 y:b1 z:c1,test.proj x:a2 y:b2 z:c2
```

`ExpandedA` is similar to `B` in your original question; it is the expanded version of `A` but without any metadata.  Then I run the `CopyMetadata` target once for each item in `ExpandedA` (thanks to item batching).  Each run, the original `A` item is copied to the `ExpandedAMetadata` item group along with all of its metadata.  The `Original` metadata is used to ensure that the correct `A` item is associated with each file.  Finally, in the `Print` target, `B` is constructed using an item transformation, so that all the metadata from `ExpandedAMetadata` is copied over as well.

Comment: Nice solution, I like the way you used batching to do that. But every time I need to copy metadata I'll need to write an extra "CopyMetadata" target to do the batching. I find myself copying metadata too often, I hoped there would be some "CopyMetadata" task or something similar that would allow me to do this without the overhead of writing another target for every copy operation. (perhaps a "CopyMetadata" inline task...)

Answer (score 3):

Little late, but I like this solution better:

```
<B Include="@(A->Metadata('files'))" />
```

Full Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

    <ItemGroup>
        <A Include="A1">
            <files>a1_file1.htm;a1_file2.htm</files>
            <x>a1</x>
            <y>b1</y>
            <z>c1</z>
        </A>
        <A Include="A2">
            <files>a2_file.proj</files>
            <x>a2</x>
            <y>b2</y>
            <z>c2</z>
        </A>
        <B Include="@(A->Metadata('files'))" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <Target Name="Build">
        <Message Text="A: @(A->'%(Identity) x:%(x) y:%(y) z:%(z) files:%(files)', '&#x0D;&#x0A;   ')" />
        <Message Text="B: @(B->'%(Identity) x:%(x) y:%(y) z:%(z) files:%(files)', '&#x0D;&#x0A;   ')" />
    </Target>

</Project>
```

Output:

```
Build:
  A: A1 x:a1 y:b1 z:c1 files:a1_file1.htm;a1_file2.htm
     A2 x:a2 y:b2 z:c2 files:a2_file.proj
  B: a1_file1.htm x:a1 y:b1 z:c1 files:a1_file1.htm;a1_file2.htm
     a1_file2.htm x:a1 y:b1 z:c1 files:a1_file1.htm;a1_file2.htm
     a2_file.proj x:a2 y:b2 z:c2 files:a2_file.proj
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I get what you need, but you can copy all A metedata to B as in the [answer for related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5165476/copy-items-metadata-in-msbuild):

```
<B Include="@(A)">
```

It should copy all metedata from A to B.

Comment: No. I need to create a B item for every file in files metadata, not for every A item as you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a direct answer to the original question:

```
  <!-- Copy all metadata from an input item to an output item -->
  <UsingTask
    TaskName="CopyMetadataTask"
    TaskFactory="CodeTaskFactory"
    AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0.dll" >
    <ParameterGroup>
      <InputItem ParameterType="Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITaskItem" Required="true" />
      <OutputItem ParameterType="Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITaskItem" Required="true" />
    </ParameterGroup>
    <Task>
      <Using Namespace="System"/>
      <Code Type="Fragment" Language="cs">
        <![CDATA[
          InputItem.CopyMetadataTo(OutputItem);
        ]]>
      </Code>
    </Task>
  </UsingTask>
```

You can use this task to copy metadata between items the way it was originally intended, and it can easily be adapted to multiple items on input/output, though doing so does induce issues whereby it is necessary to match the inputs and outputs 1/1, or make other compromises, though it can easily be adapted to the exact situation since you can modify the C# code however is necessary. E.g.:

```
  <UsingTask
    TaskName="CopyMetadataTask"
    TaskFactory="CodeTaskFactory"
    AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0.dll" >
    <ParameterGroup>
      <InputItem ParameterType="Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITaskItem[]" Required="true" />
      <OutputItem ParameterType="Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITaskItem[]" Required="true" />
    </ParameterGroup>
    <Task>
      <Using Namespace="System"/>
      <Code Type="Fragment" Language="cs">
        <![CDATA[
          for (int i = 0; i < InputItem.Length; ++i)
          {
            InputItem[i].CopyMetadataTo(OutputItem[i]);
          }
        ]]>
      </Code>
    </Task>
  </UsingTask>
```

The task can then be called to copy metadata directly, for example (using the second version):

```
<ItemGroup>
  <ItemListA Include="a;b;c" Metadata="MetadataValue" />
  <ItemListB Include="d;e;f" OtherMetadata="OtherValue" />
</ItemGroup>
<CopyMetadataTask InputItem="@(ItemListA)" OutputItem="@(ItemListB)" />
```